# How can I set different learning rates for different sets of weights in the same Keras layer?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

If I have a given Keras layer

```
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers, optimizers

# Define custom layer
class MyCustomLayer(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyCustomLayer, self).__init__()
        self.set_1_weights = self.add_weight(shape=(input_shape[1], 10), name='set_1_weights')
        self.set_2_weights = self.add_weight(shape=(10, output_shape[1]), name='set_2_weights')

    def call(self, inputs):
        x = tf.matmul(inputs, self.set_1_weights)
        output = tf.matmul(x, self.set_2_weights)
        return output
```

I want to use the Adam optimizer with a learning rate of 0.01 on the first set, while using a learning rate of 0.001 on the second, for example.

Tensorflow addons has a [MultiOptimizer](https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/api_docs/python/tfa/optimizers/MultiOptimizer), but this seems to be layer-specific. Is there a way I can apply different learning rates to each set of weights in the same layer?

Comment: In your code block, set_1 and set_2 are batched in the different layers.   Could you be clear about the sets of weights? Do you want to get multiple optimizers in same model or layer?